# how to update many integer values back to their respective columns in database in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

i have datagrid that load information from database and when each row is selected like this each columns shows in one textbox1 like this;

```
private void dgvGrade_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        DataRowView dr = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (dr != null)
        {
            
            if (dgvGrade.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var obj in dgvGrade.SelectedItems)
                {
                    txtids.Text += dr["IDNO"].ToString();
                    str += dr["ENGLISH"] + "   " + dr["MATH"] + "    " + dr["SOCIAL"] + "   " + dr["SCIENCE"] + "   " + dr["PRETECH"] + "   " + dr["ICT"] + "   " + dr["RME"] + "  " + dr["HOMEECOMICS"] + "  " + dr["HISTORY"] + "   " + dr["OWOP"] + "   " + dr["CREATIVEART"] + "   " + dr["FRENCH"] + "   " + dr["LANGUAGE"] + " " + " ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //DO NOTHING
            }
            txtresults.Text = str;
        }
```

and after changes each digit in the textbox1 i would like to save each value back to the database to each column so i tried this;

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(shoolmanangmentconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_TestingTheApplicationSubject SET MATH=@MATH, ENGLISH=@ENGLISH, SOCIAL=@SOCIAL, SCIENCE=@SCIENCE, RME=@RME, PRETECH=@PRETECH, HOMEECOMICS=@HOMEECOMICS,  HISTORY=@HISTORY, OWOP=@OWOP, ICT=@ICT, FRENCH=@FRENCH, CREATIVEART=@CREATIVEART, LANGUAGE=@LANGUAGE WHERE IDNO=@IDNO", Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string[] arryval = txtresults.Text.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int i = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNO",txtids.Text)**; // TODO: use correct value of IDNO
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENGLISH", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATH", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOCIAL", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCIENCE", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRETECH", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICT", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RME", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOMEECOMICS", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HISTORY", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OWOP", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATIVEART", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FRENCH", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LANGUAGE", arryval[i++]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but i end up saving only one row  in its IDNO columns but i have many IDNO columns selected as well but i don't know how to save each row back according to there IDNO Numbers please can some one help me out please (am using c# wpf)

Comment: Why not edit in the datagrid or use a listview and bind selecteditem so wpf bindings sort out what row is being edited?

Comment: am actually changing the values to a grade form that's why please try to help me this way if you can please am begging

Comment: please Andy how do i do that which you suggested